# Less Files Name standards

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I have two questions. I'm using `less.js` and I'm new with it.

1) Why do we put `_` (underscore) after the file name.less?

2) Is there any file that can reset the value of the tags - I think it's called a prefix file, and it resets the values for html and body tags: `h1`, `h2`.

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

html, body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Is there any ready file to do this for me?

Answer (score 1):

1. Less does not require `_` (underscores) in file names.
2. You can use:

   - [reset-css](https://github.com/shannonmoeller/reset-css) an unmodified copy of [Eric Meyer's CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)
   - [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/) that makes browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards